# SimpleXMLElement get value from specific node

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I'm trying to use simplexml to get a specific value inside a tag, from a html string. Here's the simplexml sample output:

```
    SimpleXMLElement Object (

    [comment] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 

    [div] => Array ( 

        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object (

             [@attributes] => Array (

                 [class] => col left 

             ) 

             [mod] => name 
        ) 

        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 

            [@attributes] => Array ( 

                [class] => col right ) 

                [mod] => name 

        ) 

    ) 

 )
```

What I need is extract only the values (and key, if possible) from [mod] nodes, regardless of number of divs or other elements present in the string, and assign the values to an array.

Comment: Is it impossible in PHP to search all the multidimensional array for a specific key, and return de values? I've been trying a million ways with diferent functions but no luck so far.